# How to programmatically click element and send the click event to another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a situation where the response of a click is handled like this:

```
//File A
$(document).on("click", function(evt) {
    if (validateEvent(evt)) {submitEvent(evt.target); return(false);};
});
```

And I need to programmatically click an element on the document:

```
//File B
$('#myButton').click();
```

But unfortunately the `.click()` on the element does not trigger the `$(document).on("click")` code, solely the click handler of the element.

How could I either

1. Click the element, capture that event, and send the event to the `validateEvent()` function.
2. Create a click event on the element to send to the `validateEvent()`
   function.
3. Trigger the document's click handler and tell it that the event belongs to the `#myButton` element?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dispatchEvent` to dispatch an event on the element #myButton like so:

```
var clickEvent = new Event('click');
$('#myButton')[0].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

Comment: Forgive me if I am misunderstanding, but in this usage is `.dispatchEvent()`not just doing the same thing as `.click()` would? I am not understanding how `.dispatchEvent()` could be implemented in a way that would create a click event for the element, do the click of the element, and also send the button's click event to the `document`'s click handler.